# Fixed element inside positioned div with scroller?

Tags: html, css, layout, position

I am trying to get an absolutely positioned element to stay in its position while someone scrolls the content of the parent div. I've read many questions about applying positioning to the parent div of either absolute or relative, but still can't seem to get an absolute positioned element inside of a scrolling div to work. The content inside the div is greater than the height of the div. How to get the child div to maintain its position through the scroll?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/724vpsLf/1/

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="abs">
        Abs Arrow
    </div>
</div>

#wrap {
  position: fixed:
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 80%;
  width: 200px;
}
#abs {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 0px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `position: absolute`, try `position:fixed`. `position:absolute` won't work the way you use it. ;)

---

CSS + HTML:

```css
    #wrap {
      position: fixed:
      top:0;
      left:0;
      height: 80%;
      width: 200px;
    }
    
    #abs {
      position: fixed;
      bottom: 10px;
      right: 0px;
      background: #f00;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<div id="wrap">
<div id="abs">
Abs Arrow
</div>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>
Content<br>


</div>
```

Hope it helped :)

Comment: Problem is that makes it relative to the window, it needs to be relative to the div because the div could be positioned in multiple spots on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Are you after something like this?

```css
#parent{
  position: relative;  
}
#wrap {
  position:absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color:#EFEFEF;
  overflow:visible;
}
#abs {
  position:fixed;
  top: 20px;
  background: #f00;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="abs">Abs Arrow</div>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
  <p>Content goes here</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand, abs is relative to the window not the wrapper.

Comment: Wouldyou please explain the exact desired output in simple words?

Comment: To have an absolutely positioned element relative to its parent wrapper or div. The parent div will have its own size and location within the window, and the absolutely positioned div within it needs to be relative to it, not the window, which is why fixed positioning won't work.

Comment: I strongly recommend adding a semantic image with descriptons, as I am unable to understand what do u need exactly